# Why can't pdb access a variable containing an exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, exception, pdb

Sometime, I can't identify when or what's causing it, pdb will not help you with code like:

```
try:
    foo()
except Exception as e:
   import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

You end up with the usual prompt, but trying to access `e` will lead to:

```
(pdb) e
*** NameError: name 'e' is not defined.
```

It's not all the time of course, and it happens on linux, windows, my machine, my colleague machine...

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In Python 3, the target of an `except .. as target` statement is cleared when the suite exits. From the [`try` statement documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement):

> When an exception has been assigned using as `target`, it is cleared at the end of the except clause. This is as if
>
> ```
> except E as N:
>     foo
> ```
>
> was translated to
>
> ```
> except E as N:
>     try:
>         foo
>     finally:
>         del N
> ```
>
> This means the exception must be assigned to a different name to be able to refer to it after the except clause. Exceptions are cleared because with the traceback attached to them, they form a reference cycle with the stack frame, keeping all locals in that frame alive until the next garbage collection occurs.

Calling `pdb.set_trace()` effectively exits the block, so the implicit `finally` suite above is executed.

Bind the exception to a different name:

```
try:
    foo()
except Exception as e:
   exception = e
   import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
```

Demo:

```
>>> try:
...     foo()
... except Exception as e:
...    exception = e
...    import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
...
--Return--
> <stdin>(5)<module>()->None
(Pdb) e
*** NameError: name 'e' is not defined
(Pdb) exception
NameError("name 'foo' is not defined",)
```

Comment: > "Calling `pdb.set_trace()` effectively exits the block" - only if it's the last call in that block. Which kinda looks like a bug in `pdb` :).